# Does HDFS replication increase the total storage on the file system?

Tags: file, hdfs, storage, replication

[HDFS Mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y32C.png)

If each block is saved multiple times for fault tolerance (say 3 times), then does that mean that a 100TB datafile actually takes 300 TB size on the HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. The data must be stored on 3 different data nodes, and therefore it duplicated 3 times.